# Array initialization and method count increase ? What's the secret?

Tags: ruby, arrays, methods, initialization

This Question may be weird or i am plain dumb.

```
>> Array.methods.count
=> 97
>> a = Array.new.methods
=> 167
```

What causes the increase in number of methods after an array has been initialized and assigned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are counting two things: class-methods and instance methods. You may compare it with `instance_methods`

```
p Array.methods.count          #->  97
p Array.instance_methods.count #-> 167
p Array.new.methods.count      #-> 167
```

Or take a look if `new` is a valid method:

```
p Array.methods.include?(:new) #true
p Array.instance_methods.include?(:new) #false
```

`new` is only defined on the class, not in the instance.